# VB6: Datagrid only view the saved data after saving

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I'm new to this visual basic 6.0 can you tell me what happens in this?

I have 1 Microsoft ADO Data Control 6.0(OLEDB) on my form and I connected it on my database(*.mdb) and my recordsource on the properties of adodc1 is connected using: SELECT * FROM UsersDB 'This is my command text sql

and this is the code:

```
Dim str As String

Private Sub Form_Load()
LoadEmployee
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click()
If btnSave.Caption = "Save" Then
    Adodc1.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM UsersDB Where Name='" & txtName.Text & "'"
    Adodc1.Refresh

    If Adodc1.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "This name already exists. Please chose another."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Adodc1.Recordset.AddNew
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Name") = txtName.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Date_of_Birth") = txtDOB.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Age") = txtAge.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Gender") = cmbGender.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Address") = txtAddress.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Father's_Name") = txtFathersname.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Mother's_Name") = txtMothersname.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Contact_Number") = txtContactNumber.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Hobbies") = cmbHobbies.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Picture") = str
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Usertype") = cmbUsertype.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Username") = txtUsername.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Password") = txtPassword.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Update
    MsgBox "Successfully added to the database", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Success"
    btnSave.Caption = "Add New"
ElseIf btnSave.Caption = "Add New" Then
    txtName.Text = ""
    txtDOB.Text = ""
    txtAge.Text = ""
    cmbGender.Text = ""
    txtAddress.Text = ""
    txtFathersname.Text = ""
    txtMothersname.Text = ""
    txtContactNumber.Text = ""
    cmbHobbies.Text = ""
    cmbUsertype.Text = ""
    txtUsername.Text = ""
    txtPassword.Text = ""
    Image2.Picture = Nothing
    btnSave.Caption = "Save"
End If
End Sub
```

What happens here is that on running the program I load all the information which is currently connected to database(via form load()). and after I save it all the data in the datagrid vanishes and the only thing left is the new saved data which I currently save. How can I retrieve all of the data along with my new saved data on the datagrid?

This is my work:

[My Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuJGs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
If btnSave.Caption = "Save" Then
    Set DataGrid1.DataSource = Nothing
    Adodc1.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM UsersDB Where Name='" & txtName.Text & "'"
    Adodc1.Refresh

    If Adodc1.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "This name already exists. Please chose another."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Adodc1.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM UsersDB"
    Adodc1.Refresh
    Set DataGrid1.DataSource = Adodc1
    DataGrid1.Refresh

    Adodc1.Recordset.AddNew
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Name") = txtName.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Date_of_Birth") = txtDOB.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Age") = txtAge.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Gender") = cmbGender.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Address") = txtAddress.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Father's_Name") = txtFathersname.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Mother's_Name") = txtMothersname.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Contact_Number") = txtContactNumber.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Hobbies") = cmbHobbies.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Picture") = str
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Usertype") = cmbUsertype.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Username") = txtUsername.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Password") = txtPassword.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Update

    MsgBox "Successfully added to the database", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Success"
    btnSave.Caption = "Add New"

ElseIf btnSave.Caption = "Add New" Then
    txtName.Text = ""
    txtDOB.Text = ""
    txtAge.Text = ""
    cmbGender.Text = ""
    txtAddress.Text = ""
    txtFathersname.Text = ""
    txtMothersname.Text = ""
    txtContactNumber.Text = ""
    cmbHobbies.Text = ""
    cmbUsertype.Text = ""
    txtUsername.Text = ""
    txtPassword.Text = ""
    Image2.Picture = Nothing
    btnSave.Caption = "Save"
End If
End Sub
```